# How can I access the current URL when a view is rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I  access the  current url  when a view is rendered ?

That means,
when i access http://mypage.com/index I have to show 
"index" in an html division in my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you're after action name

Untested but something along this lines:

```
<%= this.ViewContext.RouteValues["action"] %>
```

Maybe you'll have to access controller context (hence untested).

### If you're after the actual URL

Manipulate controller action URL as you wish

```
<%= Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName") %>
```

### If you're after URL on the client

Then Javascript is your friend:

```
window.location
```

has the value you need